# Filtering an array of objects from an API endpoint

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, filter

I'm currently getting back an array of objects called `Skills` from an API Endpoint.  I am attempting to filter out the `skills` object and return a new array. I will then pass down this as props to a child component named `SkillsDetails` 
The problem that I am currently having issues with is that I want this new filtered array from the parent component `SkillsTable` to have a condition to only return the object with the matching `skillsId` that i'm currently using in a child component.

So in return I would like my new filter array to only appear in my child component if it is matching the `skillsId`.

Here is my skills array :

```
0: {id: 5, profileName: "Jon Snow", skillId: 3, comment: "test", location: "N/A", City: "NY"}
1: {id: 5, profileName: "John Smith", skillId: 4, comment: "testing", location: "N/A", City: "NYC"}
```

Filter in the `SkillsTable` component:

```
const skillsDetals=(skills => skills.filter === skillsId) => {
return skillsDetails
```

Skills Details:

```
const SkillsDetails= ({ skillsId}) => {
    console.log(skillsId, "skills");
    const classes = useStyles();


    useEffect(() => {
        getSkillsDetails(skillsId);
    }, []);
```

Comment: What array filtering have you  tried so far? Where are you getting stuck?

Comment: I am attempting a filter method in my const skillsDetails function. when console.logging skillsDetails I am getting a returned of undefined.

Comment: Do you want to filter skills object by id only so that you can have only one skill object in the array?

Comment: I am attempting to filter skills object by skillsId in order to return the entire objected that matches with that specific id so for example if skillsId = 3, I would like the entire object with profileName, comment, etc

Comment: I think what you want is the first function getSkillDetail.

Answer (score 1):

[array::filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) takes a callback function to call with each element of your array. The call back returns true for any elements you wish to keep in the new returned array.

```js
const skills = [
  {id: 5, profileName: "Jon Snow", skillId: 3, comment: "test", location: "N/A", City: "NY"},
  {id: 5, profileName: "John Smith", skillId: 4, comment: "testing", location: "N/A", City: "NYC"},
];

// array filter callback function
// destructures the current element's `skillId` property
function skillIdFilter({ skillId }) {
  return skillId === this;
}

// array.filter(currentElement, thisArgInCAllback)
const filterBySkillId = (array, skillId) => array.filter(skillIdFilter, skillId);

console.log(filterBySkillId(skills, 3));
console.log(filterBySkillId(skills, 4));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
const skillsDetals=(skills => skills.filter === skillsId) => {
   return skillsDetails
}
```

^^^ this function should be something like below.

```
// Find target skill detail that matches the given target skill id  
const getSkillDetail = (skills, targetId) => skills.find(({skillId}) => skillId === targetId);

//e.g. getSkillDetail(skills, 3);
//return {
//  "id": 5,
//  "profileName": "Jon Snow",
//  "skillId": 3,
//  "comment": "test",
//  "location": "N/A",
//  "City": "NY"
// }
```

If you want to filter multiple items that matches multiple properties with values.

```
const filterSkills = (skills, props) =>
    skills.filter(skill =>
        Object.keys(props).every(key => props[key] === skill[key]),
    );

//e.g. filterSkills(skills, {skillId: 3})
//return [
//  {
//    "id": 5,
//    "profileName": "Jon Snow",
//    "skillId": 3,
//    "comment": "test",
//    "location": "N/A",
//    "City": "NY"
//  }
//]
```